# Confidence Score For Trained Sentiment Analyser Model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, accuracy, sentiment-analysis

I have trained a text based sentiment analysis model, using SciKit-learn and custom data. I have the model ready and it works fine in predicting a text to a class (Positive or Negative or Neutral). I have achieved over *85%* testing accuracy and around *80%* cross validation accuracy.

But I want to get the **confidence score** attached to each of my prediction to a new example data/text I feed to the classifier. This is just an **extra parameter** I want to show/output apart from just the predicted class.

I have no idea how to achieve this, I shall be really thankful if anyone can provide some helpful insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself after some further research. 
I will be briefly describing my approach here.
Cheers!

The idea is to find the [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) which was also same as finding the distance from the decision boundary / hyper-plane, in my case.

If you are using the Scikit Learn API, there is a method called **predict_proba()** for several classification models like Logistic Regression, SVM, Random Forest, etc. If your classifier does not provide one, you can wrap it with the *CalibratedClassifierCV* which can be found in *sklearn.calibration*, then use the above method to calculate the distance from the decision boundary.

If you are looking for custom in-depth implementation, here are some papers / references that might help.

- [Ref - 1](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta101.2/lectures/STA101lecture15.pdf)
- [Ref - 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608006000153)